# MATLAB's dblquad can integrate more convoluted function but can't integrate simpler function

Tags: matlab

When I define a function handle

> F = @(x,y)y*sin(x)+x*cos(y);

and call *dblquad* over a compact region, I get an answer

> dblquad(F,0,2,0,2)
>
> ans =
>
> 4.650888508453225

However when I do the same thing with the simpler function handle

> F = @(x,y)x^2+y^2;

I get an error and I can't figure out what's going wrong. I guess there must be something I dont understand about dblquad. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I see the problem now. You should be using elemnt wise calculations:

```
F = @(x,y)x.^2+y.^2;
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help.